# Resizing QPixmap while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: python, pyqt

To keep the aspect ratio of an image fixed while resizing the `QDialog` I've tried the following:

```
import os, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QGridLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pic = QLabel()
        self.pic.resizeEvent = onResize 
        self.pic.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.getcwd() + "/images/1.jpg").scaled(300, 200, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pic, 1, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

def onResize(event):
    size = dialog.pic.size()
    dialog.pic.setPixmap(QPixmap(os.getcwd() + "/images/1.jpg").scaled(size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As espected the Image starts with 300x200. It can be enlarged as wished but the size can't be reduced at all (down to 300x200 after enlargement). `onResize` seems to lack something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a working example for this problem. Don't use `setPixmap` method to draw the pixmap on the widget, draw it by reimplementing `paintEvent` of widget.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class Label(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, img):
        super(Label, self).__init__()
        self.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        size = self.size()
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        point = QtCore.QPoint(0,0)
        scaledPix = self.pixmap.scaled(size, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, transformMode = Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        # start painting the label from left upper corner
        point.setX((size.width() - scaledPix.width())/2)
        point.setY((size.height() - scaledPix.height())/2)
        print point.x(), ' ', point.y()
        painter.drawPixmap(point, scaledPix)


class Main(QtGui.QWidget):          
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        label = Label(r"/path/to/some/image.png")
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.setRowStretch(0,1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0,1)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Copy whole code and run it as it is. Then try to scale the window that appears. Then understand the `paintEvent` in `Label` class. Dont forget to change the path to some existing png image in `__init__` of `Main` class.

**UPDATE** FOR CHANGING THE IMAGE:

To change the image you can add a method `changePixmap(self, img)` to `Label` class and call it on an event on which you want to change the pixmap.

```
...
def changePixmap(self, img):
    self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(img)
    self.repaint() # repaint() will trigger the paintEvent(self, event), this way the new pixmap will be drawn on the label
```

You can call the method from `Main` class by saving the reference to `Label` class in a member variable.

```
...
self.label = Label('/path/to/image.png')
...
```

Then inside any event in `Main` class, call `self.label.changePixmap('path/to/new/image.png')`

Comment: How can I change the displayed image after it has been set initially?

Answer (score 0):

Your onResize is a free function, not a method of class Dialog (look at the indentation, and the absence of 'self') so it never gets called.